# "JWT Validation Failed: JWT not present.." in Azure API Management Service

Tags: azure, api, oauth-2.0, azure-api-management, jwt

For reference I am attempting to reproduce the solution talked about here: https://www.tech-findings.com/2020/02/securing-logic-app-with-azure-active-directory.html to use API Management to secure an Azure Logic App.

I am getting a JWT Error. When I visit the app url in the browser it gives:

```
{ "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }
```

In the API Management Service test I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

Following the trace through it shows:

```
validate-jwt (-0.111 ms)
{
    "message": "JWT Validation Failed: JWT not present.."
}
```

I did some googling and tried the solutions at:
[JWT validation failure error in azure apim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57703697/jwt-validation-failure-error-in-azure-apim)
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/108008/azure-apim-jwt-token-validation-policy.html

Here is the inbound policy of from the API Management design:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-method id="apim-generated-policy">POST</set-method>
        <rewrite-uri id="apim-generated-policy" template="/request/paths/invoke//?api-version=2016-06-01&amp;sp=/triggers/request/run&amp;sv=1.0&amp;sig={{[[LOGIC APP NAME]]_request-invoke_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}}" />
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Request is not authorized or token failed" require-expiration-time="false" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
            <openid-config url="https://login.windows.net/[[TENANT NAME]].onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
            <audiences>
                <audience>[[THE ID OF A REGISTERED APP]]</audience>
            </audiences>
        </validate-jwt>
        <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="delete" />
        <set-header name="apim-generated-policy" exists-action="delete" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

This is the manifest of the registered app:

```
{
    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
    "addIns": [],
    "allowPublicClient": null,
    "appId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "appRoles": [],
    "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
    "createdDateTime": "2020-12-22T19:48:36Z",
    "disabledByMicrosoftStatus": null,
    "groupMembershipClaims": null,
    "identifierUris": [
        "api://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    ],
    "informationalUrls": {
        "termsOfService": null,
        "support": null,
        "privacy": null,
        "marketing": null
    },
    "keyCredentials": [],
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "logoUrl": null,
    "logoutUrl": null,
    "name": "LabsTestApp",
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": false,
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
    "oauth2Permissions": [],
    "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
    "optionalClaims": null,
    "orgRestrictions": [],
    "parentalControlSettings": {
        "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
        "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
    },
    "passwordCredentials": [],
    "preAuthorizedApplications": [],
    "publisherDomain": "[[TENANT NAME]].onmicrosoft.com",
    "replyUrlsWithType": [],
    "requiredResourceAccess": [],
    "samlMetadataUrl": null,
    "signInUrl": null,
    "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
    "tags": [],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
}
```

Hoping you can help out - point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hi, may I know if your problem was solved ? If still have any problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this question, there are more than one problem in your steps.

**1.** You mentioned the error `{ "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }` when you request the url in browser. The reason is when you request it in browser, it request with `Get` method but the url should be request with `Post` method. So it shows `404 not found`.

**2.** When you test in API Management service, it shows `401 Unauthorized`. The reason for this error is you did not provide the access token or the access token you provided is invalid. The steps in the [document](https://www.tech-findings.com/2020/02/securing-logic-app-with-azure-active-directory.html) you mentioned are incomplete, please refer to the steps below:

1). First please make sure you have completed all of the steps in the document you provided.

2). Then go to the app you registered in azure ad and click "**Manifest**" tab, add a appRole in the json of "Manifest".
[image]
You can specify a name(anything you want) for this role, I named the role as `Writer` as the screenshot above shows. And you can also specify a "id"(in GUID format) as the value of the `id` field in appRole. For more details of add appRole, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#example-application-app-role).

3). You need to register another app in azure ad as the client app. Do same register operation as your document shows to register the other app, I registered the app and named `huryGetToken4`. Go to this app and click "**API permissions**" tab, click "Add a permission" and find the original app you registered, then add the permission `Writer`.
[image]
[image]

After add the `Writer` permission, you also need to click "**Grant admin consent for xxx**".
[image]

Then click "**Certificates & secrets**" tab, click "New client secret" to generate a client secret. Copy this secret because it will just show one time.
[image]

4). Then you need to get access token, please refer to the screenshot below to request for access token.
[image]
In the screenshot above, you need to replace the `<tenant id>` with your tenant id in the host url. And you also need to input the first three parameters. The last parameter `grant_type` is static.

5). Request for the access token, you will get the response like below screenshot.
[image]
Copy the value of `access_token` and paste it to this [page](https://jwt.io/) to decode the token, you can see the claim `roles` with `Writer` permission in it. This claim is what you need to check in the `<validate-jwt>` policy in your APIM.
[image]

6). Go to your apim and click the `pencil` icon of `validate-jwt` policy.
[image]

7). Edit the "Reauired claims" like screenshot below:
[image]

8). After that, you can test the api in APIM service. Add a header with key: `Authorization`, value: `Bearer <your access token>`(note there is a blank between `Bearer` and access token).
[image]

Comment: Wow this is detailed. Thank you! So you're saying that I need 2 app registrations in addition to the API management service and the Logic app? Or does hte logic app count as one of the 2 registrations?

Comment: @GregViers Yes, you need to app registered in your Azure AD. One is for backend which you already registered as the document mentions(the document guide you register a app named `AudienceAppForADSecuredLogicApp`). And the other is registered as client app in your Azure AD, which I mentioned it in my answer(`3). You need to register another app in azure ad as the client app.....`)

Comment: ok so I've done all that and success - I 'm getting a different error message. But it's nothing to do with validation of hte JWT. Thanks for solving this!